# Unexpected end of JSON input file while installing material-ui v3.0.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, npm-install

I'm installing the latest stable version of material-ui(v3.03) executing: `npm install @material-ui/core`. Results in `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...-/brcast-1.1.2.tgz"}}'`.

```
node --version
v8.1.1

npm --version
v6.4.1
```

I tried downgrading npm to v5.2.0 and the error persisted. I can install other packages fine. Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` followed by `npm install` and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Can you explain what was causing the issue?

Comment: added it as an answer with some details. i don't have a definitive answer for cache corruption. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you encounter such errors you should try `npm cache clean --force` followed by the `npm install` command.

npm uses cache to install new packages. the json file in the cache must've been corrupted which resulted in the error. hence clearing the cache and doing an npm install with clean cache helped overcome the issue.

as to why there was a corrupted json file in the cache - i don't a definitive answer. it could be that the request to install the package didn't complete and hence resulted in corrupted cache.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache